# Getting updated data from table

Tags: sapui5

I have recently started working with UI5. In my current task, I have displayed data in table using `JSONModel` and by using `TextField` in template I am allowing user to update the data.

I have to get the updated complete table contents back in form of JSON so that I can update it back in database.

I have tried `Table.getContextByIndex()` and `getProperty`, however I am not getting updated data. Please let me know how this can be done.

Comment: JSONModels generally use TwoWayBinding, which means that a changed value (when bound) will be written to the model. You should try to change sth. in your table and check the table's model after that. In case that does not work we need your code.

Comment: Hi, I have checked it again, I could not see any change. Can it be because of formatter ? I am using following syntax to validate data before it is being shown in Table:bindProperty(
           "value", {parts:[{path:"Date"}],
           formatter: function(val){//Code to validate}}

Comment: Please find my Code of adding a Column: oTableContents.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column("Date").setTemplate(
new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty(
           "value", {parts:[{path:"Date"}],
           formatter: function(val){//Code to validate}})).setLabelnew sap.ui.commons.Label({
         text : "Date"
        })));

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose SAPUI5 provides two-way data binding. If a value is changed in the view, it is reflected in the corresponding model. Two-way data binding is the default binding mode. You can use the methods from model to get the data.

Comment: I agree reiner, and JSON is two-way model however I am unable to see the changes. I have tested using : oModel.getJSON() after editing contents, where oModel is object of JSONModel.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the problem. As per below link. 
Formatter functions allow one-way conversion only. This may be the reason why I am unable to see changes in model. .

[Formatting Property Values](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/91/f0652b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm)